# How to filter multiyear dataframe to retain rows with values in all years

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index, drop

I have a multiyear daily dataframe which has different entities(Col1) present in different years (Col2). I am trying to filter the data frame such that it retains only those rows which have a value in each of the specified year.
(I have created Col2 from the datetime index thinking it would make filtering process easier)

In other words, I am trying to design a conditional filter where a column value satisfying a condition in another column is retained.

This is my dataframe:

```
Date    Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
1/1/16  M   2016  34  a
2/2/16  M   2016  35  f
3/3/16  M   2016  45  d
1/1/17  S   2017  66  ff
2/2/17  S   2017  66  mn
1/1/18  T   2018  78  jh
2/2/18  T   2018  789  kk
1/1/17  M   2017  100  f
2/2/17  S   2017  2020 jj
2/2/18  M   2018  3005 m
```

Entities M,S and T record values in 2016-2019 but only M has values in all the three years.

Thus, resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
Date    Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
1/1/16  M   2016 34   a
2/2/16  M   2016 35   f
3/3/16  M   2016 45   d
1/1/17  M   2017 100  f
2/2/18  M   2018 3005 m
```

I am trying to work out the logic through following lines of code, but none work:

```
(1)
    years = [2016,2017,2018]
    
for station in df_in['Col1']:
    years = [2016,2017,2018]
    if df_in['Col2'].isin(years).any():
        df = df_in
    else:
        df = df_in.drop(df_in[df_in.Col1].index)
```

OR

```
(2)
df= df_in['Col1'].apply(lambda x: x in df_in['year'].isin(years))
```

OR

```
(3)
df = df_in.loc[(df_in['Col1']) & (df_in['Col2'].isin(years))]
```

What will be a good way of achieving this?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check with `filter` + `groupby`

```
s=df.groupby('Col1').filter(lambda x : pd.Series([2016,2017,2018]).isin(x['Col2']).all())
     Date Col1  Col2
0  1/1/16    M  2016
1  2/2/16    M  2016
2  3/3/16    M  2016
7  1/1/17    M  2017
9  2/2/18    M  2018
```

Answer (score 1):

If need compare exactly only values from `year`s list compare sets for equal in [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for mask and then filtering in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
years = [2016,2017,2018]
df1 = df[df.groupby('Col1')['Col2'].transform(lambda x: set(x) == set(years))]
print (df1)
     Date Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4
0  1/1/16    M  2016    34    a
1  2/2/16    M  2016    35    f
2  3/3/16    M  2016    45    d
7  1/1/17    M  2017   100    f
9  2/2/18    M  2018  3005    m
```

If want compare exist values from list and possible some another values per groups compare for high or equal:

```
print (df)
     Date Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4
0  1/1/16    M  2019    34    a <- 2019
1  2/2/16    M  2016    35    f
2  3/3/16    M  2016    45    d
3  1/1/17    S  2017    66   ff
4  2/2/17    S  2017    66   mn
5  1/1/18    T  2018    78   jh
6  2/2/18    T  2018   789   kk
7  1/1/17    M  2017   100    f
8  2/2/17    S  2017  2020   jj
9  2/2/18    M  2018  3005    m

years = [2016,2017,2018]
df1 = df[df.groupby('Col1')['Col2'].transform(lambda x: set(x) >= set(years))]
print (df1)
     Date Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4
0  1/1/16    M  2019    34    a
1  2/2/16    M  2016    35    f
2  3/3/16    M  2016    45    d
7  1/1/17    M  2017   100    f
9  2/2/18    M  2018  3005    m
```

Comment: @Learning_datascience - It depends of data, I test also `filter` solution and was `2.5` times slowier, so if large data or if performance is important here is better use `transform`

Comment: @Learning_datascience - `np.random.seed(123)
N = 10000
L = range(2016, 2020)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col2': np.random.choice(L, N),
                   'Col1':np.random.randint(N // 7, size=N)})`

Comment: @Learning_datascience - `In [187]: %timeit df[df.groupby('Col1')['Col2'].transform(lambda x: set(x) >= set(years))]
193 ms ± 7.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

`In [188]: %timeit df.groupby('Col1').filter(lambda x : pd.Series([2016,2017,2018]).isin(x['Col2']).all())
530 ms ± 48.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: @jezrael..This approach works on simple dataframes like the one I have used in the example. However, the actual dataframe that I am using is has multiple columns that need to be retained. Using your code on my actual dataframe is yielding an empty dataframe. I am updating my question to show what I mean.

Comment: @Learning_datascience - Do you test both second solutions? Because second should be more matched

Comment: @Learning_datascience - are values in col2 numeric? `print (df['Col2'].dtype)` return `int` or float ? Because another columns are not important here, edited answer.

Comment: @Learning_datascience - Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you dont want to hardwire the years. Please try the following
1.Extract all the unique years into a list

2. Groupby each year and generate a column with a list of all years in each group in Col1

3.Check membership by converting lists in each group to a set to eliminate
duplicates. Intersect with the list d and if length is the same boolean select

```
    d=df.Col2.unique().tolist()
    df2=df.groupby(['Col1']).Col2.agg(list).reset_index().rename(columns={'Col2':'Lst'})#
    df[pd.merge(df,df2, how='left', on='Col1').Lst.apply(lambda e:[*{*e}&{*d}]).str.len()==len(d)]#



    Date Col1  Col2
0  1/1/16    M  2016
1  2/2/16    M  2016
2  3/3/16    M  2016
7  1/1/17    M  2017
9  2/2/18    M  2018

%%timeit 
d=df.Col2.unique().tolist()
df2=df.groupby(['Col1']).Col2.agg(list).reset_index().rename(columns={'Col2':'Lst'})
df[pd.merge(df,df2, how='left', on='Col1').Lst.apply(lambda e:[*{*e}&{*d}]).str.len()==len(d)]
7.5 ms ± 45.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```